# ¿Cómo puedo reescribir este código para que el programa devuelva variantes con los datos una sola vez ingresados?

Tags: python, python-3.x

El programa debe devolver nombres con los datos ingresados una sola vez por el usuario y de acuerdo a la cantidad de variantes ingresadas armar al azar esa cantidad de nombres. Pero tengo el problema que vuelve a pedirme el tipo de letra vocal, consonante u otra letra la cantidad de variantes deseadas:

```
import random, string

vowels = 'aeiouy'
consonants = 'bcdfhjklmnpqrstvwxz'

while True:
    try:
        cantLetras = int(input('Elige la cantidad de letras: '))
        cantVariantes = int(input('Eliga la cantidad variantes que desea: '))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print('Por favor introduzca una cantidad numérica')



def generator():
    name = ''

    for i in range(cantLetras):

        letter_input = input('Choose a letter... "v" for vowels, "c" for consonants, "l" for any other letter')

        if letter_input == "v":
            letter = random.choice(vowels)
        elif letter_input == "c":
            letter = random.choice(consonants)
        elif letter_input == "l":
            letter = letter_input
        else:
            letter = letter_input

        name += letter

    print(name.capitalize())

def multi_generator():
    for x in range(cantVariantes):
        generator()

multi_generator()
```

Comment: tu función de `multi_genereator()` está llamando a `generator()` la cantidad de `cantVariantes`.

Comment: En primer lugar, dado que el ultimo `elif` y el `else` hacen lo mismo, el hecho de que el usuario ingrese una **l** es lo mismo q si ingresa cualquier otra letra diferente de **v** y **c**, o sea, esa condicion esta de mas. En segundo lugar, el usuario no tiene forma de decir _quiero escoger una v o una c_, pues el codigo termina seleccionando una vocal o una consonante aleatoria.

Answer (score 0):

Podrias reemplazar la funcion por esta

```
letter_input_list = [input('Choose a letter... "v" for vowels, "c" for consonants, "l" for any other letter') for x in range(cantLetras)]

def generator():
    global letter_input_list
    name = ''

    for letter_input in letter_input_list:


        if letter_input == "v":
            letter = random.choice(vowels)
        elif letter_input == "c":
            letter = random.choice(consonants)
        elif letter_input == "l":
            letter = letter_input
        else:
            letter = letter_input

        name += letter

    print(name.capitalize())
```

El error que tienes, es que el input lo pides varias veces para formar la palabra hasta ahí esta bien, pero a su vez llamas varias veces a esa funcion por lo que el comportamiento de  pedir varias veces la palabra se multiplica; por ello la solución que encontré fue usar una variable global para almacenar las elecciones de palabras.

Pd: Deberías tener en cuenta las limitaciones matemáticas de esto, por si no quieres que se repitan.